# A result in the solution of wave equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

> Let $u$ be a smooth solution of the initial-value problem
>   $$
> \left\{
> \begin{aligned}
> u_{tt} - u_{xx} &= 0\qquad \text{in}~ \mathbb{R}\times (0,\infty)\\
> u=g,\quad u_t&=h\qquad \text{on}~\mathbb{R}\times \{t=0\}
> \end{aligned}
> \right.
> $$
>   Suppose that $g$ and $h$ are sufficiently smooth and have compact supports. \
>   Define $p(t) := \frac{1}{2} \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty u_x(x,t)^2\,d x \quad\text{and}\quad k(t) := \frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty u_t(x,t)^2\,d x\,.$
>
> 1. Prove that $E(t):= k(t) + p(t)$ is constant in $t\geq 0$.
> 2. Prove that $p(t)=k(t)$ for all large enough times $t$.

**My Attempt:**

For the part 1, I was trying to prove that $\frac{d}{dt}E(t)=0$.
Hence we have, 
\begin{align}
E^{'}(t)&=k^{'}(t)+p^{'}(t)\\
&=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty u_x.u_{xt}+\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty u_t.u_{tt}\\
&=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty  u_x.u_{xt}+\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty u_t.u_{xx}
\end{align}
But after that what should I do..

Also for part 2, I know that from the D'Alambert's Formula, we have $$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}[g(x+t)-g(x-t)]+\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{x-t}^{x+t}h(y)dy \tag{1}$$
So I'm trying to prove that when $t\to\infty$, $p(t)-k(t)=\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}u_x^2-u_t^2=0$. But I'm having a hard time in differentiating $(1)$ to get the suitable values.
Appreciate your help

Comment: Hint: Use integration by parts on the first integral. It will become the negative of the second integral.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. So when applying the integration by parts, for an open set $U$, $\int\limits_{U}u_{x_i}v=-\int\limits_{U}uv_{x_i}+\int_{\partial U}uv\nu^ids$,  what should I do to the third integral runs along the boundary. Is it correct if I consider $u=g(x)$ in the boundary and hence, $u_t=0$

Comment: In this case the boundary is very far off in the $x$, so what is $\lim_{x\to\infty} u(x,t)$ according to D'Alembert's formula?

Comment: oh I see.That means is it correct to say that,  Since $g$ and $h$ has a compact support, they become zero for a sufficiently large $t$. Hence $u$ becomes zero. Hence its derivatives are also zero.. ?

Comment: That's exactly what compact support means. All possible derivatives vanish. (This extra notion is critical for distributions where they can vanish everywhere but still have nonzero derivatives).

Comment: Thank you very much for the idea. and just to make it sure... can you explain why does the integral term in D'Alembert's formula becomes zero. If it doesn't we can't say that $u$ becomes zero right?

Comment: The integral vanishes if you take the $x$ limit for a fixed time only since eventually the domain of integration leaves the support of $h$

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have according to D'Alambert's formula

$$\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}u_t(x,t) \to \frac{1}{2}\left( g'(\pm \infty)+g'(\pm\infty)\right) + \frac{1}{2}\left(h(\pm\infty)+h(\pm\infty)\right) = 0$$

by the compact support of $g$ and $h$. Using this, we can pick up where you left off and show that

$$E'(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty u_x u_{tx}\:dx + \int_{-\infty}^\infty u_t u_{xx}\:dx = u_xu_t\Bigr|_{-\infty}^\infty -\int_{-\infty}^\infty u_t u_{xx}\:dx+\int_{-\infty}^\infty u_t u_{xx}\:dx = 0 $$

hence $E(t)$ is constant. For the second part, use D'Alembert's formula to get equations for the first partial derivatives:

$$u_t(x,t) = \frac{1}{2}\left( g'(x+t)+g'(x-t)\right) + \frac{1}{2}\left(h(x+t)+h(x-t)\right)$$

$$u_x(x,t) = \frac{1}{2}\left( g'(x+t)-g'(x-t)\right) + \frac{1}{2}\left(h(x+t)-h(x-t)\right)$$

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty u_t^2 - u_x^2 \:dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty(g'(x+t)+h(x+t))\cdot(g'(x-t) + h(x-t))\:dx$$

The question, however, does not ask for a limiting behavior of $t$. It implies a discrete switching behavior that happens for some finite $t$.

Taking a look at the integral, notice that if $t > |\operatorname{Supp}(g+h)|$, then for any point $x$ in the domain of integration, one of the terms in the integrand's product will always be $0$

Thus there exists $T = |\operatorname{Supp}(g+h)|$ such that $\forall t > T$:

$$k(t) - p(t) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty u_t^2 - u_x^2 \:dx = 0$$

Physically, the first part demonstrates the conservation of energy, taking $k(t)$ to be kinetic energy and $p(t)$ to be potential energy. The second part demonstrates the principle of least action since the quantity $k(t) - p(t)$ is called the Lagrangian.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation